# Perl: Verify the command line argument is an integer and not a file

Tags: perl

I need to check if the (Perl) command line argument is only an integer and a file.

I can check is the right number of arguments are entered:

```
if (@ARGV != 2){
```

And, I can check to make sure the order of arguments is correct:

```
    if ($ARGV[0] >= $ARGV[1])
```

But, I don't know how to check if the argument is a file. I want to print and error message if it is a file.

Thanks

Comment: Surely if either of the arguments isn't an integer, the `>=` comparison will cause an error?

Comment: No, it defaults to one of the print errors in the code.

Comment: That would be a warning: "Argument isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) ...".
Which only errors if you have `use warnings;` at the beginning of your script. Which you should, for that and other reasons.

Comment: What if the argument is both an integer and a file?  I can create a file called `3`...

Answer (score 8):

You can do this manually with a few checks.

```
sub usage {
    return "$0 <integer> <filename>\n";
}

if( @ARGV != 2          ||    # right number of arguments
    $ARGV[0] !~ /^\d+$/ ||    # first one is an integer
    !-f $ARGV[1]        ||    # second is a readable file
    !-r $ARGV[1]
) {
    die usage();
}
```

Note there's no need for an extra check that arguments are in the correct order.

---

Or you can do it with a module like [Getopt::Args](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Args). This is the better solution as it's declarative, and removes a lot of redundancy and potential for mistakes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;
use Getopt::Args;

arg integer => (
    isa         => 'Int',
    required    => 1,
    comment     => 'an integer',
);
arg filename => (
    isa         => 'Str',
    required    => 1,
    comment     => 'a filename',
);

# Extra checks for a readable filename.
my $args = optargs();
if( !-r $args->{filename} ||
    !-f $args->{filename}
) {
    die usage();
}
```

It will produce its own usage message.

```
$ perl ~/tmp/test.pl
usage: test.pl INTEGER FILENAME

  Arguments:
    INTEGER    an integer
    FILENAME   a filename
```

For future programs it will handle `--options` and subcommands as well.

If you don't like this one, [there are many Getopt modules to choose from](https://metacpan.org/search?q=getopt).

Comment: I like the use of the `-r` there... quite important.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-f` to check if a given string is a file or not. For more options, see [perldoc -X](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html).

In your example as I understood it:

```
die 'First argument is a filename!' if -f $ARGV[0];
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for the -f. I forgot about die.

Answer (score -1):

To test if, say, $ARGV[0] is strictly integer, you could use this predicate:

```
if ($ARGV[0] =~ /^\d+$/) {
    print "an integer\n";
} else {
    print "not an integer\n";
}
```

Execute `perldoc perlre` for a whole lot more information.

To test if $ARGV[0] is a file, you would use something like this:

```
if (-f $ARGV[0]) {
    print "a file\n";
} else {
    print "not a file\n";
}
```

Execute `perldoc -f -f` for quite a bit of information on file related tests.

Comment: In most cases, what you mean by an integer should, in a regex, be matched via `[0-9]`. Unless you *want* to allow utf number symbols generally.